# Undefined reference to main ld

Tags: c, windows, assembly, ld

I'm trying to link to files - a c file containing a main function and an asm file that simply jumps to the main.

I have mingw installed.
My files:

```
//kernel.c
void some_function(){
}
void main(){
char* video_memory = (char*) 0xb8000;
*video_memory = 'X';
some_function();
}

;kernel_entry.asm
[bits 32]
[extern main]
call main
jmp $
```

The commands I call to build:

```
gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
nasm kernel_entry.asm -f elf -o kernel_entry.o
ld -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 kernel_entry.o kernel.o
```

The errors I'm getting:

```
kernel_entry.o:(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `main'
kernel.o:kernel.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `__main'
```

EDIT:

Which commands work:

```
ld -r -o kernel.out -Ttext 0x1000 kernel.o
objcopy -O binary -j .text kernel.out kernel.bin
```

When I try to run ld with -r i get an error:

```
ld: Relocatable linking with relocations from format elf32-i386 (kernel_entry.o)
 to format pe-i386 (kernel.bin) is not supported
```

EDIT2:
I had the best results when using these commands:

```
gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
nasm kernel_entry.asm -f win32 -o kernel_entry.o
ld -r -o kernel.out -Ttext 0x1000 kernel_entry.o kernel.o
objcopy -O binary -j .text kernel.out kernel.bin
```

The files linked succesfully, but when running, the main never gets called.
Also tried with coff format, it also links, but Bochs keeps restarting.

Comment: Have you tried `extern _main, call _main` ?

Comment: that fixed the first error, the second one in kernel.c still persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error is is because in C a function is named `_name`, so you can not call `main` as such, you must call `_main`. In TASM you can set the calling convention, so the assmebler automatically can call the right function, I don't know if there is such a feature for nasm as well.

The second problem is probably, because you are calling the linker directly. In this case you must specify the C startup module, which is normally added by the compiler to the linker options. Usually I think this is a file named something like `crt0`. If you write your own startup code, you must provide this yourself. This module sets up the environment for C from the OS specific entry point. I guess this is missing in your project.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0

Comment: i have used -r for ld, and it linked fine

Comment: the -r option works only when i link kernel.o only since it seems that kernel.o has a different format than elf32

Comment: is it possible to have gcc create an object in the elf format in windows?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You create a *.bin file, which looks as if you create a standalone assembly module. So why would you need an ELF? Who would load this?

Comment: i am trying to create a bootloader - since i am not guaranteed that the c compiler will not change the order of functions and data, i am trying to prepend a small asm code that will call the function main.

Comment: That's what I thought. So ELF doesn't really help you, because there is no code that will understand ELF or any other format. Your asm must be the entry point, and then you must call the C module so your asm part must setup the environment that a C module expects. And you must compile with no stdlibs (which is what I was aiming at in my answer above). You might take a look at the code from GRUB to get an idea.

Comment: But why does the code work when I do not prepend the asm code? I do not setup anything for the code to work.