# MinGW Win32 + nasm: "undefined reference"

Tags: gcc, assembly, mingw, nasm, undefined-reference

I am currently developing an OS for learning purposes, and it's been working fine until now. Then I tried to call an assembler function, compiled with `nasm, -fwin32`, from C code, but all I got was an "undefined reference" error. I have created a small example in pure assembler, which has the same problem, but is easily understandable and way smaller:
It includes two files:

**test.asm:**

```
[bits 32]
global _testfunc
_testfunc:
    ret

test2.asm:

[bits 32]
extern _testfunc
global _testfunc2
_testfunc2:
    call _testfunc
    ret
```

Here is my compiler / linker script (using windows batch files):

```
nasm.exe -f win32 test.asm -o test.o
nasm.exe -f win32 test2.asm -o test2.o
ld test.o test2.o -o output.tmp
```

This results in the error:

```
test2.o:test2.asm:(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `testfunc'
```

To extend the question, the same happens when the function is called from C:

**test.c:**

```
extern void testfunc(void);
void start()
{
    testfunc();
}
```

With this linker script:

```
gcc -ffreestanding -c test.c -o testc.o
nasm.exe -f win32 test.asm -o test.o
ld test.o testc.o -o output.tmp
```

In test.o, test2.o and testc.o, it always says `_testfunc`, so the error has nothing to do with leading underscores!

Comment: Your issue in C is apparent: `extern void testfunc(void);` is nothing more than a promise to the compiler that `testfunc` is defined somewhere else. If during compile, `testfunc` cannot be found defined as you promised, you get the error at issue. Where is `testfunc` defined? As for nasm, I suspect the same is occurring, but I do not write enough asm to know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but isn't testfunc defined in test.o? That's what the global does, isn't it?

Comment: No. all I see is `test.c` -- and there all you have is an extern declaration - No storage is assigned to `testfunc` and there is no `definition`. Do you have another C file? test2.c somewhere? I don't know if you definition in test.asm can suffice.

Comment: Looking, don't you need `[global _testfunc]` and `[global _testfunc2]` in the asm files?

Comment: If you read the asm files again, you'll see that they do contain the global declarations.

Comment: Shot in the dark here, Are there any capitalization errors or conflicts present ?  Not trying to be annoying, that's just the only thing that I can remember that I've done when something like this came up.

Comment: @JanWeber you are correct. But don't you need to wrap the declaration in `[]` in your asm files?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin To be honest, I never understood the difference. But I tried both, so I just decided that it doesn't matter.

Comment: Awh! Live and learn. Take a look at this link [**Undefined reference to main ld**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165891/undefined-reference-to-main-ld)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my MinGW setup you need a `section` directive before the code.

```
; foo.asm
[bits 32]
global _testfunc
section .text
_testfunc:
    ret
```

Then assemble to win32 format:

```
nasm -fwin32 foo.asm -o foo.o
```

Now you can check that `testfunc` is there:

```
$ nm foo.o
00000000 a .absolut
00000000 t .text
00000001 a @feat.00
00000000 T _testfunc
```

The `T` means text section global, so we're good to go.

Note I'd avoid naming anything `test` since this is a shell command.  This can cause endless grief.

The C function is as you showed it, but name the file something else:

```
// main.c
extern void testfunc(void);
int main(void)
{
    testfunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Then to build an executable let `gcc` do the heavy lifting because `ld` sometimes needs arcane arguments.

```
gcc -ffreestanding main.c foo.o -o main
```

Answer (score 2):

Your missing something important, your code is not in a code section!

Your asm files should look like the following:

`test.asm`

```
global _testfunc

section .text       ; <<<< This is important!!!        
; all code goes below this!                                                  
_testfunc:

    ret
```

`test2.asm`

```
extern _testfunc
global _testfunc2

section .text       ; <<<< Again, this is important!!!                                                          
_testfunc2:
    call    _testfunc
    ret
```